# how to hide a specific column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, windows, forms, ado.net

I want to hide a specific column named `staffPassword` in `datGridview` when 
`btnViewAll` is clicked. For which I tried the below code but it does not 
work. It displays

> "System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object"

and also the Password column is still 
displaying.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetStaff]
as
SELECT Stf.StaffId as 'Staff Id',
    Stf.StaffName as 'Name',
    Stf.staffUserName as 'Username',
    Stf.staffPassword as 'Password',
    Stf.staffPhone as 'Mobile No.',
    Stf.staffRole as 'Role',
    Stf.staffStatus as 'Role Status'
FROM tblStaff Stf ORDER BY Stf.StaffName ASC
```

```cs
public override void BtnViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    loadData(dataGridViewStaff, "SNo", "sp_GetStaff");                
    dataGridViewStaff.Columns["staffPassword"].Visible = false;
}

public static void loadData(DataGridView gv, string colNameOfSerialNo, string getStoredProcedureName)
{
    string cs = ........
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getStoredProcedureName, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gv.DataSource = dt;

    int rowCount = 1;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gv.Rows) 
    {
        row.Cells[colNameOfSerialNo].Value = rowCount; 
        rowCount++;
    }
}
```

```sql
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_GetStaffPassword]
@staffId varchar(150)    
as
SELECT Stf.staffPassword as 'Password'
FROM tblStaff Stf WHERE staffID=@staffId
```

```cs
private void DataGridViewStaff_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1) 
    {
        string cs =.......
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetStaffPassword", con); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffId", staffID);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdr);

        con.Close();

        txtPassword.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); 
        txtConfirmPassword.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

        txtPhoneNo.Text= dataGridViewStaff.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Mobile No."].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: i almost see no null checks in the code. where exactly are you getting null reference ?

Comment: @aspxsushil The exception is thrown at below code: dataGridViewStaff.Columns["staffPassword"].Visible = false;

Comment: then check the name of grid view column "staffPassword"

Comment: I guess it should be dataGridViewStaff.Columns["Password"].Visible = false; because that's the column name your stored procedure returns